# c++ standard library header not recognized

Tags: c++, header-files, semaphore

I'm working on a multithreaded project in c++ and am trying to use a semaphore, [from what I read in the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore) c++ has a semaphore, but when I try to include the header

> `#include <semaphore>`

It does not autocomplete and I get a compiler error saying the header file is not recognized.
[According to the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/semaphore),

> *This header is part of the thread support library.*

Does this mean I would need to add some prefix to the `#include`? Or include some other dependant header?  I can't figure out why this won't work and I can't find anything about this anywhere, any help would be appreciated.

I'm on a temporary machine and just installed visual studio on it a couple of days ago, so everything should be up to date.

Comment: It is c++20 feature, i don`t know if there are compilers that support it, you probably need to to wait some time

Comment: If you look carefully at the documentation page you'll see that the whole thing is marked `(since C++20)`. This standard hasn't been finalized yet so it shouldn't be surprising that your compiler hasn't implemented some of the features.

Comment: Oh I see, I had read *since* and assumed it was already a feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), none of the listed compilers have currently implemented this c++20 feature.